# jQuery - using next()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following situation, I would like to add a class "highlight" to the succeeding `div.second` when `div.first > a` is clicked.

html:

```
<li>
    <div class="first">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        text to be highlighted
    </div>
</li>
<!--(repeats)-->
```

js:

```
$("div.first > a").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.second").addClass("highlight");   
});
```

I know its wrong, but I don't know how to do it correctly. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) finds the next sibling of the *current element*. Your current element is `<a>`, which, in this case, has no siblings (the poor thing). Use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to retrieve the containing `<div>`, and *then* use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to find `<div>` that is to be highlighted.

```
$("div.first > a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("div.second").addClass("highlight");   
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've tried to get parent() working by using parent("div.first") and that didn't do it. But yours works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.first > a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("div.second").addClass("highlight");   
});
```

you need to up one to the `a`'s parent and then get it's next `div`